# Different values for PidlidPrivate property in MAPI?

Tags: mapi

I am studying a MAPI property called PidLidPrivate. I find it has different values in different official document.

In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidprivate-canonical-property, the property ID is 0x8506.

However, in the sample message in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-pst/5ee9a00a-858b-47db-95b3-f91518640ea7, its property ID is 0x8020.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is right - it is the property *id*.

The second one is the property *tag* in a particular message store.

The former is what you pass to `IMAPIProp::GetIdsFromNames`. Its value is the same for all stores. The latter is what `IMAPIProp::GetIdsFromNames` returned for that id (`0x8506`) for that particular message store. The actual value will vary from store to store.

Comment: I use MFCMAPI, which always show property tag for PidLidPrivate as 0x8026000B, for different PST files.

Comment: In my PST file, it is `0x8013000B`'.

Comment: For IMAPIProp::GetIdsFromNames, one shoud pass an array of names. How can I pass a property ID(first one) to this function?

Comment: `GetIdsFromNames` does not take an array if names - it takes a pointer to an array of pointers pointing to MAPINAMEID structures, MAPINAMEID structure lets you specify the guid, id kind (int vs string) and a union of int/string id.